# Installing a version of Windows with a manufacture tie in, on a VM?

Tags: windows-xp, virtual-machine

I need to install Windows XP on a VM (Parallels) in order to run a very specific piece of old software.

Im very conscious that i dont want to get an installer from anywhere as it could very easily come bundled with malware.

My thought was to buy a brand new in box copy from eBay (I know this is not fool proof, but the best solution i could come up with).

The problem is the copies I can find on eBay are either without the serial number (so presumably no good unless i use a cracked serial, which i dont want to do), or branded as "for dell hardware" or "for siemens hardware" etc..

If i was to try and install a copy of XP which has a manufacture tie in as above, would it work on Parallels ? Or is there somewhere else i should be looking ?

Comment: It'll probably work. The only difference between the manufacturer specific installer and vanilla Windows is - typically - the former has additional drivers slipstreamed. Those drivers aren't needed for the virtualized hardware so they won't be used but everything else should be the same. Please do NOT give network access to the VM though.

Comment: I purchased a good and valid Vista Business package on eBay some years back and was satisfied with my contact of the seller. It worked, activated and is still working today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as the XP box comes with a valid license key you are good.
These OEM branded versions (that originally came bundled with computers) are normally identical to the normal XP, with maybe some extra drivers slipstreamed (that you won't use in a VM anyway).
They just have an added manufacturer startup logo and show the brand name when you open the "Properties" of "This PC". That is just cosmetic.

Please note: If you have access to a Microsoft VisualStudio account you can download an XP image with key from Visualstudio.com as well. Access to various media and keys for old Windows versions is part of the benefits that come with such an account.

Comment: Thanks, is a visual studio account a paid membership ?

Comment: @sam - The account is free. A subscription to a license to a paid version of Visual Studio is not obviously. The license that Tonny suggests is relatively expensive.

Comment: @sam Unfortunately it is not free and rather expensive. But you (or maybe another colleague at work) may already have it. From personal experience I know that not everybody who has such a subscription realizes that there is a whole bunch of licenses for Microsoft software that go with it. At my office more than 50 developers have such a license to use VisualStudio, but most of them didn't realize they had these licenses too at first. We now compensate a large part the cost of VisualStudio with the money we save on unneeded licenses  for the test-systems.